# Why do we use function calc and stack to do raster calculation? Is that better than using our desire function directly?

Tags: r, stack, raster, calc

Recently, I need to calculate the mean of 12 world climate raster layers. There are two ways we can do. The first one is more direct:

```
mean.layer <- mean(L1, L2,......,L12) # L1 means the first layer
```

or

```
mean.layer <- (L1+L2+......+L12)/12
```

Another is new to me:

```
layer.stack <- stack(L1,L2,......,L12)
mean.layer <- calc(layer.stack, mean, na.rm = T)
```

Can someone explain the advantage of using `calc` and `stack` instead of using `mean` function directly? In my knowledge, we can manipulate the raster data in the same resolution and extension directly.

---

2021.7.10 edited. I rewrite the second method to correct some mistype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always please include some example data

```
library(raster)
b <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
```

These two statements are equivalent

```
x <- mean(b)
y <- calc(b, mean)
```

But `calc` has a filename argument, so you can save the results to disk in one step.

`calc` is especially advantageous when working with large rasters and more complex functions. For example

```
z1 <- calc(b, function(i) 100 - sqrt(mean(i + 10)))
```

Is equivalent to this

```
z2 <- 100 - sqrt(mean(b + 10))
```

But the latter may need to write 4 temp files to store the values, while the former would only need 1 such file.

Your should avoid approaches to get the mean like this

```
 mean.layer <- (L1+L2+......+L12)/12
```

It is cumbersome to write, prone to error, and does not scale (imagine doing this for 1200 rasters!).

I do not know where you found the formulation with `calc` in your question, but that makes no sense, and does not work.

Comment: Thank you so much @RobertHijmans. Because my files are very large, I don't know how to make them easy to share. For your detailed explanation, is clear and truly solves my question.